# Json data shows error in angular 6 subscribe method

Tags: angular, angular6

I am getting error in json response in .subscription method in my angular 6 project.

This is service page

```
get_data(url,auth=true){
        var get_url = API_URL + url;
        return this.httpClient.get(get_url) .pipe((map((response: Response) => response )));
    }
```

and here is my component page

```
this.data.get_data('user/getUsers',true).subscribe(data => { this.users =data.data;});
```

here i am getting below error

> Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Response'.
>   This is my api json response

```
{
"status": 1,
"message": "success",
"data":[
    {"id": 6, "first_name": "Test", "last_name": "programmer"},
    {"id": 5, "first_name": "James\r\n", "last_name": "Reynolds"},
    {"id": 4, "first_name": "Kelly", "last_name": "Gregory"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i don't think we can 100% answer your question with the given information but you can debug this yourself easily:

Output the whole response as a string (json.stringify) and the mistake should become clear :)

If not, then reply to this comment with the output, maybe we can help you then.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are getting JSON String format, you should use this,

```js
this.data.get_data('user/getUsers',true).subscribe(data => {
data = data.json();
this.users =data.data;}}
```

then proceed to use data.data

Comment: i know this is not exactly proper way to solve, but try without pipe

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
return this.httpClient.get(get_url,{responseType:'json'}) 
  .pipe((map((response: Response) =>  response )));
```